# How to open new web browser instead of pop up on click of link which has seperate http session from parent window

Tags: java, javascript, session, web-applications

I have parent window and provided a link. For now I am using below code snippet to open a pop up window

```
self.open(pageLoc,'ServicePopUp','height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
```

but I want to open completely new browser (like we open a new instance of webbrowser on click of IE) on click of link not a pop up window so that new browser has seperate session from parent window. 
How should I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't.

Sessions are identified by cookies, which are browser-wide -- any session available to the parent window will be available to your child window.

There's two ways to go about this, a "good" way and a "hacky but probably easier" way.

---

**The good way:**

Code you site such that it can emulate this multi-session behavior. Maybe have a special parameter in the url that identifies this as a new-session window, and then have a separate block of data that you treat as your session for these windows.

**The hacky way**

Set up wildcard dns, such that any subdomain of your site will show the same thing (i.e. www.yoursite.com == aoeu.yoursite.com == qjkx.yoursite.com etc), then open the popup at a randomly generated subdomain. Ensure that your cookies for your main site specify that they only apply to www.yoursite.com, and then visits to the subdomain'd sites won't have access to the session information

Comment: Thanks Mala for such a great reply. But How can i ensure that my cookies for main site specify that they only apply to www.yoursite.com. I mean where i need to change for this?

Comment: You will need to use the 'domain' attribute of the cookie. How you set that depends on what language you're using. If Javascript, see http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php. If PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Question is: Why do you want the new window to retain no information about the previous session?

Comment: actually iwant to attach the different session with new window because of mine some rquirement.what is happening now is there are two two links link l1 and l2 which opens two seperate browser windows W1 and W2. Now what i set in session for W1 is also visible in W2 session. Thats why i want to attach seperate session to both windows.

Answer (score 0):

when you open a new window a reference to the new window is returned so you could possibly use that to gain access to the new window and execute javascript cookie creations on it if you save the reference to a variable.